# How can I store and display a date value in a JavaScript variable from a MySql query in php script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

When I insert data (date) in my table and click on the add button it changes it into 0000-00-00 instead of the entered date.
Please tell me how to store the date into the javascript variable.

```
//php code
<?php
    $edate = mysqli_query($con, $_POST["edate"]);
    $query = "INSERT INTO expenses(edate, details, spent) VALUES('$edate', '$details','$spent')";
?>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
    var edate = $('#data1').text(); 
</script>
```

Comment: Your PHP is completely wrong. See here for some good examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First print your date in a hidden input field in your PHP file

```
<input type="hidden" class="myDate" value="$dateFromyourDatabase">
```

Then get it in your JS

```
var myDate = $(".myDate").val();
```

I have used html class attr, you can use whatevery seems easy to you

Comment: Thanks so much, I totally got your point. I was stuck with this for almost a week. Thanks ALOT!